# VMWare - I Deleted a Server, But the .vdmks Still Exist

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Here is the back story --

I had consolidation/snapshot problems with a VM server.

To solve it I ended up cloning the server, and using the clone.

I deleted the original in VCenter, "Delete From Disk" not "Remove From Inventory".

Now looking at my datastore, the old server is not gone from there, it is still there. I checked in on the new server, and it is not using any of the .vdmk files for discs. Am I safe to delete the directory for the older server? Is there some other things I should check before doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are ***ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN*** the .vmdk files are not being used anywhere else you should be able to safely delete them.

I would suggest archiving them (copy them to some other system) first. Sometimes even when you're "absolutely certain" you're wrong and things break. It's useful to be able to restore the files in such cases.

Comment: Well I know there are not being used by the server that I cloned with them, at least not directly. If I renamed the directory that contains them, would that be a good test whether or not they are in use?